# Driverpack Notifier shows up on Alt+Tab

Tags: windows-7, windows

This started since i started installing Games on my PC(torrent from years ago).

Any case, i searched for this particular software and it said that it's mainly used for windows 7 sp1 and i run that os windows 7 sp 1.

[Alt+Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxzNL.png)

[Windows edition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NfhO.png)

My problem is that, whenever i ALT+TAB Driver Pack Notifier shows up and i don't see it anywhere indicating that it's running.(It probably is[it probably is running deep in my windows] but idk why it constantly shows up on my alt+tab, prevention is better than cure).

See Below:

Should i be worried?(P.S. cant post more than 2 links, i'll add them in comments)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZysq.png
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTe40.png
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceX7l.png

Comment: It's probably running as a service ...

Comment: If you have an taskbar icon, then a process/service does exist, and is listed in task manager.  You failed to show all your processes though.  Any event you should locate the exectuable and remove it.

Comment: Show processes from all users?

Also, my main question is, will this cause a problem?

Comment: @DavidPostill but why is it showing up in my ALT+TAB?

This is my main concern.